# Zenity command to output SHA-256 hash

Tags: linux, sha256, zenity, arch

So I plan to use a zenity information message box to output a SHA256 within a "nemo_action". I have tried many different methods to accomplish this - none have so far been successful.

Below is my most recent failure:

```
zenity --info --title="Check SHA256 for %n" --text="$(sha256sum %f)"
```

and when added to nemo_actions:

```
Exec=zenity --info --title="Check SHA256 for %n" --text="$(sha256sum %f)"
```

Thank you for your time.
David.

Answer (score 1):

nvm.
I have created a shell script and put it in the nemo scripts folder.

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$(zenity --file-selection)
sha256sum $file
```

Comment: Worth an UV for your persistence in answering your own question. However, you need to quote `"$file"` in `sha256sum $file` to prevent word-splitting if the filename contains whitespace.